# Difference between two clicks didn't get well on this code

Tags: javascript, click, addeventlistener

I'm new to javascript and that is why I'm asking this question. I just want the alert "unlocked" if the 'hash' key is pressed in a time interval of 9 sec after "key" is pressed, but it's not working as expected, can anyone help me?

```js
document.getElementById("key").addEventListener("click",function(){
alert("enter # to unlock");  
var time = (new Date()).getTime();
  //alert(time);
});

document.getElementById("hash").addEventListener("click",function(){
  var keytime = (new Date()).getTime();
    //alert(keytime);
   var diff = time - keytime;
  alert(diff);
  if(diff <= 9000){
    alert("unlocked");  
  }
  else{
   alert("try again");  
  }
  
  });
```

```html
<button id="key">key </button>
<button id="hash">#</button>
```

Comment: i think you need to use setInterval

Comment: The error message tells it all. You define time when you press the `key` button as such that the scope of time is not extended outside of the event for `key`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`time` should be a global variable so that `hash` event listener can access it.

```js
var time = Infinity;
document.getElementById("key").addEventListener("click",function(){
alert("enter # to unlock");  
time = (new Date()).getTime();
  //alert(time);
});

document.getElementById("hash").addEventListener("click",function(){
  var keytime = (new Date()).getTime();
    //alert(keytime);
   var diff = time - keytime;
  alert(diff);
  if(diff <= 9000){
    time = Infinity;
    alert("unlocked");  
  }
  else{
   alert("try again");  
  }
  
  });
```

```html
<button id="key">key </button>
<button id="hash">#</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You initialized `time` in the scope of the `#key` click listener. It can't be reach outside.

Set it outside as a global variable.

[Variable scope documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp)

```js
 
var time = 0;

document.getElementById("key").addEventListener("click",function(){
  alert("enter # to unlock");  
  time = (new Date()).getTime();
  //alert(time);
});

document.getElementById("hash").addEventListener("click",function(){
  var keytime = (new Date()).getTime();
    //alert(keytime);
   var diff = time - keytime;
  alert(diff);
  if(diff <= 9000){
    alert("unlocked");  
  }
  else{
   alert("try again");  
  }
  
  });
```

```html
<button id="key">key </button>
<button id="hash">#</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

time is a local var.

to access it in other functions you should create a global variable like this:

```
var time;
document.getElementById("key").addEventListener("click",function(){
alert("enter # to unlock");  
time = (new Date()).getTime();
  //alert(time);
});

document.getElementById("hash").addEventListener("click",function(){
  var keytime = (new Date()).getTime();
    //alert(keytime);
   var diff = time - keytime;
  alert(diff);
  if(diff <= 9000){
    alert("unlocked");  
  }
  else{
  alert("try again");  
 }

  });
```